# How to create a time counter using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a time counter which will show time he spending on that page after loaded  and on click of certain button it will stop counting and show the time he spent on that page. How do I do it using jQuery?

I have written some javaScript code but doesn't work properly. If someone help me to find the solution.Thanks in advance.

```
<html>
    <head>

        <title>Auto Refresh Page</title>
    <!--    <META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="5">-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>

        <div id="show" align="center"></div>
        <button id="myButton"></button>
        <script>


 $(document).ready(
                function () {
                function display() {
                   var startTime;
                    // later record end time
                    var endTime = new Date();

                    // time difference in ms
                    var timeDiff = endTime - startTime;

                    // strip the miliseconds
                    timeDiff /= 1000;

                    // get seconds
                    var seconds = Math.round(timeDiff % 60);

                    // remove seconds from the date
                    timeDiff = Math.floor(timeDiff / 60);

                    // get minutes
                    var minutes = Math.round(timeDiff % 60);

                    // remove minutes from the date
                    timeDiff = Math.floor(timeDiff / 60);

                    // get hours
                    var hours = Math.round(timeDiff % 24);

                    // remove hours from the date
                    timeDiff = Math.floor(timeDiff / 24);

                    // the rest of timeDiff is number of days
                    var days = timeDiff;

                    $(".show").text(days + " days, " + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds);
                    setTimeout(display, 1000);
                    }
                 $('#myButton').click(function(){
                 });
                });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are three main problems with your current code.

Firstly, you never initialise the `startTime` variable, which means that `endTime - startTime` gives you `NaN`. Move the following line out of your function so that it can retain its value in between invocations:

```
var startTime;
```

...and give it a starting value:

```
var startTime = new Date();
```

Secondly, you never actually call your `display();` function. You use a `setTimeout()` call so that it will call itself, but you need to call it the first time after you declare it. So add this line at the end of your ready handler:

```
display();
```

Finally, you are using the wrong selector for the element that is to display the time. Change:

```
$(".show").text(...
```

to be:

```
$("#show").text(...
```

If you want the button to stop the clock, you need to add a variable outside the function that will hold the id returned by `setTimeout()`, then call `clearTimeout()` from in your button click handler.

Putting that all together:

```js
$(document).ready(
  function() {
    var startTime = new Date();
    var timeoutId;
    function display() {
      var endTime = new Date(); // later record end time
      var timeDiff = endTime - startTime; // time difference in ms
      timeDiff /= 1000; // strip the miliseconds
      var seconds = Math.round(timeDiff % 60); // get seconds
      timeDiff = Math.floor(timeDiff / 60); // remove seconds from the date
      var minutes = Math.round(timeDiff % 60); // get minutes
      timeDiff = Math.floor(timeDiff / 60); // remove minutes from the date
      var hours = Math.round(timeDiff % 24); // get hours
      timeDiff = Math.floor(timeDiff / 24); // remove hours from the date
      var days = timeDiff; // the rest of timeDiff is number of days

      $("#show").text(days + " days, " + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds);
      timeoutId = setTimeout(display, 1000);
    }
    $('#myButton').click(function() { clearTimeout(timeoutId); });
    display();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="show" align="center"></div>
<button id="myButton">Stop</button>
```

Comment: Can you check once your myButton because it's actually not showing the time he spend on that page instead of stop !

Comment: I don't know what you want me to check. If you click "Run code snippet" in my answer you can see the clock counting up, then clicking the button stops the clock. That is what you seemed to be asking for, but if not it should be more than enough for you to build on yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I made a [bin](http://jsbin.com/jivugawiti/edit?html,js,console,output) and hope it will work for you, I did some changes in your code and you can modify as per your needs.

```
$(function () {
   var startTime=new Date();
                function display() {

                    // later record end time
                    var endTime = new Date();
                    // time difference in ms
                    var timeDiff = endTime - startTime;
                    // strip the miliseconds
                    timeDiff /= 1000;
                    // get seconds
                    var seconds = Math.round(timeDiff % 60);
                    // remove seconds from the date
                    timeDiff = Math.floor(timeDiff / 60);
                    // get minutes
                    var minutes = Math.round(timeDiff % 60);
                    // remove minutes from the date
                    timeDiff = Math.floor(timeDiff / 60);
                    // get hours
                    var hours = Math.round(timeDiff % 24);
                    // remove hours from the date
                    timeDiff = Math.floor(timeDiff / 24);
                    // the rest of timeDiff is number of days
                    var days = timeDiff;
                   return (days + " days, " + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds);

                }
  var settime=setInterval(function(){

     var timeSpent=display();
                   $("#show").html(timeSpent);
                 }, 1000);
   $('#myButton').click(function(){

                    clearInterval(settime);


                 });
 });
```

Comment: Actually your code works correctly But what I  wanted to say that by clicking that button counter will stop and i want to show that in another id or div may b. May be I forgot to add that in my code. can you please help me to find that out?